# Wifi device not showing up while setting up Arch Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, system-installation

I have an old laptop, on which I am planning to replace Windows with Arch Linux. I'm setting up Arch following the official wiki [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide).

After booting into the Arch ISO (BIOS mode), I got the virtual console, on which I ran `iwctl` to authenticate to the wifi network. However, on the `[iwd]` prompt, whenever I type `device list`, I get an empty list; no devices. I ran `lsusb`, and the drive is not there, too.

I am sure that a wifi drive IS there on my system, since the computer is able to connect to wifi in Windows. I have made sure that nothing is blocked by using `rfkill`, and I have tried retrying the installation from the beginning, still to no avail. Looking up online, I found a [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/im0e8c/iwctl_device_list_epty_newbie/), but no answers there work for me.

This is my first Arch installation, so I am not quite sure what else to do to fix this, so help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT**: I looked it up, my wifi driver is Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan]

**PS**: In case any extra information is needed which I haven't mentioned, do let me know, and I will update the question.

Comment: Are you set on Arch? Because if you just want to start using Linux I suggest starting with another distribution that has an installer. Arch is a great way of learning, but to get started you might want to use Debian or Fedora.

Comment: @Thorian93 I'm quite set on Arch. I've been using Ubuntu for more than a year now, and I want to try this distro for learning :)

Comment: Alright, just wanted to make sure. :)
Could be a driver issue, can you provide more information on your hardware, specifically the WiFi Card? Also could you try and set everything up using LAN and handle the WiFi situation later? I am no Arch or hardware guru, so just trying to give hints here.

Comment: Hey @Thorian93, sorry for the late response! My driver is Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan]. Also, I tried setting it up with LAN, still no luck. I guess the system's not detecting either of the drivers. Can it be an issue with the ISO file?

Comment: Please update your question with the information so everyone can see it. :)
I am not that much in the Arch setup process, but yes it sounds like a driver issue, but I don' think the iso is faulty. Maybe someone more Arch savvy can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to power on the adapter [with this command](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/iwd):

```
adapter adapter set-property Powered on
```

In my case:

```shell
adapter phy0 set-property Powered on
```

This fixed my problem.

Comment: (1) Please show the command clearly and cleanly, and put commentary on a different line. (2) If the device doesn’t appear anywhere, how is the user supposed to know its name?